# Using an environment variable name as function argument

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to figure out how to use an environment variable name in a function, passed in as a function argument, i.e.:

```
function! myautoloadfunc#set_default_env_var(name, value)
  if empty($a:name)
     let $a:name = a:value
  endif
endfunction

call myautoload#set_default_env_var('SOME_VAR', 'SOME_VALUE')
```

Obviously that doesn't work, I'm pretty sure I can do this with `exec`, but not sure if there's a more efficient way. Any suggestions?

**Edit: It seems that the following works:**

```
call myautoload#set_default_env_var('$SOME_VAR', 'SOME_VALUE')
```

Comment: Why do you think `:execute` is not efficient?

Comment: Ignorance, I suppose. I just don't know.

Comment: `exec 'let $' . name . '=' . string(value)`

Comment: Maybe the vim built-in function `fnameescape()` could help you?

Comment: @nfarrar If you found a working solution to your problem it would be better if you could post it as an answer rather than putting it in your question ;-)